# How do I call a specific key in a list containing nested dictionaries?

Tags: json, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm playing around with python and JSON files. I'm doing a simple game as a learning project, but I can't fetch a nested key in a list on demand when I want to. In the below example I'm trying to get the name of the player.

This is the JSON file (`player_sheet_daniel.json`):

```
[
    {
        "sheet_header": {
            "player name": "Daniel",
            "character name": "Ulrik the Blob"
        }
    },
    {
        "prim_attr": {
            "STR": "11",
            "DEX": "12",
            "HP": "15",
            "SKI": "16"
        }
    }
]
```

I've tried:

```
import json
with open('player_sheet_daniel.json','r') as sheet_json:        
    sheet_py = json.load(sheet_json)                 
    for section in sheet_py:                         
        print(section['sheet_header']['player name'])
```

I get: `KeyError: 'sheet_header'`.

Comment: Only one `section in sheet_py` actually contains the key `'sheet_header'`.

Comment: Yes, I thought that would be ignored... So I need to make an if check before the call then... dunno. Thanks.

Comment: Why would it be? You could either check `'sheet_header' in section` first, or use `section.get('sheet_header')`, or guard with a `try:` and `except KeyError;`.

Comment: I thought it would work with the first iteration and then fail, since the first section contains the key. But since I got no output at all I thought I had a different problem. But many thank you for your response, I've been stuck on this for 2-3 hours....
I did this to solve it:
`if 'sheet_header' in section and 'player name' in section['sheet_header']:`

Comment: Alternatively if the bit you want is always first in the array use `section = sheet_py[0]` rather than the loop.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that first, but I'm kind of allergic to solutions like that since I'm a Linux engineer and seen code failing so many times because "someone" did changes to the read source/config file(s)   :)

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON example is an array which wraps two objects. So, the correct  python syntax would be :

```
import json
with open('player_sheet_daniel.json','r') as sheet_json:        
    sheet_py = json.load(sheet_json) 
    section = sheet_py[0]                      
    print(section['sheet_header']['player name'])
```